# list.sort в C# как list.sort в Python

Tags: c#

python:
есть list tuple-ов (каждый tuple в свою очередь состоит из 3-х int-ов)
при сортировке данных методом list.sort() вначале лист сортируется по первому параметру в tuple, далее с учётом первого параметра сортируется уже второй параметр и третий с учётом первого и второго, то есть получим что-то такое

```
(0, 1, 2560)
(0, 50, 2564)
(0, 50, 30596)
(0, 16990, 2560)
(0, 16990, 2564)
(0, 23495, 30596)
(1, 3, 2597)
(1, 30, 2566)
(1, 30, 2567)
(1, 10056, 2597)
(1, 10056, 2599)
(1, 10058, 2566)
```

как сделать такю же сортировку, но уже в C#, ведь list.sort() в C# так не может

Comment: Можно и с помощью `List.Sort` - есть перегрузки метода, принимающие компаратор.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

всем спасибо :)

сделал использую linq через orderby :)

```
 edges_and_triangles =
 edges_and_triangles.OrderBy(x => x[0]).ThenBy(x => x[1]).ThenBy(x => x[2]).ToList();
```